# Can you recover parameters from Jenkins parameterised build after restarting a Jenkins instance?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

I have a Jenkins pipeline job that is configured to use a Jenkinsfile and is parameterised. After a restart of the Jenkins instance, in the job the 'Build with Parameters' option is replaced with 'Build Now' and it seems like 'Build with Parameters' only comes back once you start a build. The first build will almost always fail because it requires some of these parameters.

Is there a way to have 'Build with Parameters' (with the parameters specified in the jenkinsfile) as the default Build option in the job? Or is there even a way to save/recover the 'Build with Parameters' properties?

Thanks in advance.

Jenkins Version used: 2.319.1

Example Jenkinsfile used:

```
properties([
    parameters([
        string(defaultValue: 'mlos3_latest', description: 'Project Build Node Label', name: 'projNodeLabel')    
    ]) 
])

node(params.projNodeLabel) {//doSomething}
```

Comment: Can you give an example Jenkinsfile and Jenkins version you are using. The very first time a pipeline is created/run, it uses the default values (if specified) or empty values (`""`). After that you should see the Build with parameter option even after a restart. If you are not seeing it after a restart, it could be a Jenkins bug and you should file an [issue with Jenkins](https://issues.jenkins.io/projects/JENKINS/issues)

Comment: @PraveenLobo I've edited the original post to show an example Jenkinsfile. Jenkins version is 2.319.1. It's worth noting that this is a very simple Jenkinsfile we have that we use for testing, other Jenkinsfiles have product specific parameters where the build could actually fail if nothing get's passed in and we can't have every team changing their Jenkinsfiles

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having the properties in Jenkins file.

create the same parameters in your job configuration  with the same name and type and remove it from your jenkins file .

Hope this works-out for you .